# Xcode 5.1 Error spawning child process: Permission denied

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode5.1

The error:

```
Error spawning child process: Permission denied
```

pops up in the console about one in every five or ten times that I try to run my project in the Xcode simulator. When this happens the project does not run.
Rerunning the project (Cmd-R again) usually works.
Can't find any mention of the error on Google, anyone experiencing this?

Edit 2014-07-04, getting this error too.

[image]

Running XCode 5.1

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: Anything in the system log (see Console.app)?

Comment: This is all that I get: `3/17/14 12:16:34.990 PM sim[5185]: Error spawning child process: Permission denied`

Comment: That doesn't look like the system log?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Macs, but I opened the console app, cleared it and ran the project again and I think that's the only line that corresponds to the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: No, I cannot find anything like that on Google or Apple's Developer Forums.  Why are you starting the iOS Simulator every time?  Surely it should only need starting the first time?

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find anything either. And I just use Cmd-R to run the simulator, I don't close it and re-open it.

Comment: I had same issue. I changed simulator to iPhone Retina (3.5-inch ) and then back to Simulator back to iPhone Retina (4-inch ). it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah, I'm gettings it on the 3.5" simulator as well.  Also this:

[Dead bootstrap subset.]

Comment: I am also getting the same error sometime, Can anybody got the solution?

Comment: @trojanfoe sys log : `Jul 10 11:42:58 USER Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[54711]: assertion failed: 13C64: libxpc.dylib + 28286 [81ED694C-488A-3466-8AA2-7E0518B10AED]: 0x5
Jul 10 11:42:59 USER ibtoold[54708]: CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
Jul 10 11:42:59 USER sim[54717]: Error spawning child process: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after some Product -> Clean the message disappeared. So you should try that way!

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do a clean build of the project and restart both the Xcode 5.1 and the iOS Simulator to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I removed a few lines of commented code, and cleaned the build, before compiling it again. Sounds crazy, but it worked.

Are you having any LLDB errors along with the "Error spawning child process" one?

Comment: I'm not getting any others, oh and by the way, I only get this in one of my projects.

Answer (score 0):

I'd same issue with xcode5.1.1. Resolved by following steps.

- Clean build
- Change simulator selection to iPhone Retina 4 and Run ,    then back
  to iPhone 3.5 screen, it works.